# How to wrap Class into an object?

Tags: ios, class, wrapper

I need to store a `Class` in NSDictionary. Is there any other way than doing it with NSStringFromClass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use setObject: forKey:

A class is a valid item that can be passed to setObject which takes in id for argument.

Comment: an object is an instance of a class

Comment: sorry for the miscommunication. I actually meant that the class item can be passed on to setObject without issues and in a hurry put it up as a class is a valid object. my bad.

Answer (score 1):

```
@class MyClass;
MyClass* myObject;
[myDictionary setValue:myObject forKey:@"key"];
```

and Bob's your uncle. You don't need to convert a class into anything to put it into a dictionary.

If you want to store the dictionary in NSUserDefaults, into NSData, or somesuch, take a look at answers specifically for that. For example, search here at StackOverflow for `[ios] custom class NSUserDefaults`, or look into conforming to NSCoding.